# Can a TestNG cross-browser test be executed with Cucumber runner?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

I am working with Selenium Webdriver with Cucumber. My tests work as expected with that combination. In order to achieve cross-browser testing, I added TestNG framework. To verify that my cross-browser test was working good, I ran it with TestNG alone, without Cucumber. It ran perfectly in both Chrome and Firefox browsers.

```
public class WebTest {


  WebDriver driver = null;
  BasePageWeb basePage;
  public String browser;


  @Parameters({ "Browser" })
  public WebTest(String browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
  }

  
  @BeforeClass
  public void navigateToUrl() {
    switch (browser) {

      case "CHROME":
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;

      case "FF":
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;

      default:
        driver = null;
        break;
    }
    driver.get("https://demosite.executeautomation.com/Login.html");

  }

  @Test
  public void loginToWebApp() {

    basePage = new BasePageWeb(driver);
    basePage.enterUsername("admin")
            .enterPassword("admin")
            .clickLoginButton();

    driver.quit();
  }
```

}

The testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">

    <test name="Chrome Test">
        <parameter name="Browser" value="CHROME"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.web.WebTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Firefox Test">
        <parameter name="Browser" value="FF"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.web.WebTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I needed to integrate the TestNG test with my Cucumber set-up so that I can run the whole test with Cucumber. To do this, I added cucumber-testng dependency to POM and created a Cucumber runner extending the AbstractCucumberTestNG class. I specified the location of my feature file and step definition. The step definition is mapped to the TestNG test.

Cucumber runner:

```
@CucumberOptions(
                plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/surefire-reports/cucumber",
                        "json:target/surefire-reports/cucumberOriginal.json"},
                glue = {"stepdefinitions"},
                tags = "@web-1",
                features = {"src/test/resources/features/web.feature"})
          
   

 public class RunCucumberNGTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    }
```

Step definition:

```
public class WebAppStepDefinitions {
      private final WebTest webTest = new WebTest("CHROME"); //create an object of the class holding the testng test. If I change the argument to FF, the test will run only on Firefox
      static boolean prevScenarioFailed = false;
    
    
      @Before
      public void setUp() {
        if (prevScenarioFailed) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Previous scenario failed!");
        }
    
      }
    
      @After()
      public void stopExecutionAfterFailure(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        prevScenarioFailed = scenario.isFailed();
      }
    
      @Given("^I have navigated to the web url \"([^\"]*)\"$")
      public void navigateToUrl(String url) {  test
        webTest.navigateToUrl(url); //calling the first method holding the testng
      }
    
    
      @When("^I log into my web account with valid credentials as specicified in (.*) and (.*)$")
      public void logintoWebApp(String username, String password) {
        webTest.loginToWebApp(username, password); //calling the second method holding the testng
      }
    }
```

On running the class, the test got executed only in one browser (Chrome). Somehow, Firefox got lost in the build-up. I suspect that I am calling the parameterised TestNG method wrongly from another class. How do I do the call successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For running TestNG tests with Cucumber you have to define *Test Runner* classes in testng.xml.

your *Test Runner* class is `RunCucumberNGTest`.

So the xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">

    <test name="Chrome Test">
        <parameter name="Browser" value="CHROME"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="some.package.name.RunCucumberNGTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Firefox Test">
        <parameter name="Browser" value="FF"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="some.package.name.RunCucumberNGTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

From this xml I see the next requirements:

1. Run the same set of tests but with different parameter value.
2. This should work in parallel, so this should be thread-safe.

---

**1 Introduce TestNG Parameter for *Test Runner* class**

```java
@CucumberOptions(
                plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/surefire-reports/cucumber",
                        "json:target/surefire-reports/cucumberOriginal.json"},
                glue = {"stepdefinitions"},
                tags = "@web-1",
                features = {"src/test/resources/features/web.feature"})
public class RunCucumberNGTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    // static thread-safe container to keep the browser value
    public final static ThreadLocal<String> BROWSER = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"Browser"})
    public void defineBrowser(String browser) {
        //put browser value to thread-safe container
        RunCucumberNGTest.BROWSER.set(browser);
        System.out.println(browser);
    }

}
```

**2 Use the value in Step Definition class**

```
public class WebAppStepDefinitions {
      private WebTest webTest;
      static boolean prevScenarioFailed = false;
    
      @Before
      public void setUp() {
        if (prevScenarioFailed) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Previous scenario failed!");
        }
        //get the browser value for current thread
        String browser = RunCucumberNGTest.BROWSER.get();
        System.out.println("WebAppStepDefinitions: " + browser);
        //create an object of the class holding the testng test. If I change the argument to FF, the test will run only on Firefox
        webTest = new WebTest(browser);
      }
    
      @After
      public void stopExecutionAfterFailure(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        prevScenarioFailed = scenario.isFailed();
      }
    
      @Given("^I have navigated to the web url \"([^\"]*)\"$")
      public void navigateToUrl(String url) {
        webTest.navigateToUrl(url); //calling the first method holding the testng
      }
    
    
      @When("^I log into my web account with valid credentials as specicified in (.*) and (.*)$")
      public void logintoWebApp(String username, String password) {
        webTest.loginToWebApp(username, password); //calling the second method holding the testng
      }

}
```

---

**NOTE:** All TestNG annotations should be removed from `WebTest` class, they won't work and not required. `WebTest` used explicitly by `WebAppStepDefinitions` class, all the methods invoked explicitly and not by TestNG.

So, based on your initial requirements:

```
public class WebTest {

  WebDriver driver = null;
  BasePageWeb basePage;
  public String browser;

  public WebTest(String browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
  }

  public void navigateToUrl(String url) {
    switch (browser) {

      case "CHROME":
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;

      case "FF":
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;

      default:
        driver = null;
        break;
    }
    driver.get(url);

  }

  public void loginToWebApp(String username, String password) {

    basePage = new BasePageWeb(driver);
    basePage.enterUsername(username)
            .enterPassword(password)
            .clickLoginButton();

    driver.quit();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I applied your implementation and then ran the test via `RunCucumberNGTest` class and also via the `testng.xml` file. The test got skipped and I got the error: `org.testng.TestNGException: 
Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a @BeforeTest annotated defineBrowser.` 

Any ideas why? Would it help if I grant you access to the repo for easier debugging? Your time will help greatly and will be forever appreciated.

Comment: If you run from `RunCucumberNGTest` this won't work, since `@Parameters({"Browser"})` won't be passed. If you run from `testng.xml` it should work, if there are no any typos.. I've checked this code with TestNG v `7.4.0`. I've reproduced the error: `Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a @BeforeTest annotated defineBrowser`, when I just commented the `@Parameters({"Browser"})` line for `defineBrowser` method. Do you have `@Parameters` defined for the `defineBrowser` method?

Comment: No, I don't have `@Parameters` defined for the 'defineBrowser' method. I used exactly the same implementation you provided. The only thing I updated was the class name in `testng.xml`. I can't find the line you commented on to make the implementation work

Comment: In my example `@Parameters({"Browser"})` annotation is added for `defineBrowser(String browser)` and this is essential to make it work. I've mentioned that the error appeared for me when I removed this annotation. So  `@Parameters({"Browser"})` should be in the code.

Comment: I'm able to look throw your code if you able to share it somehow.. But, please, first confirm that you have `@Parameters({"Browser"})` for `defineBrowser(String browser)`.

Comment: Fantastic. I have added `@Parameters({"Browser"})` for `defineBrowser(String browser)`. Its working now. You are a real genius. The issue is now considered resolved. I have 2 follow-up questions though if you don't mind.

First, since the test works by running it via `testng.xml` which has the `RunCucumberNGTest` class embedded in it, should it not be possible to pass `@Parameters({"Browser"})` to the `RunCucumberNGTest` so that it can run from there also?
Second, it's a maven project so I will be running in a CI tool. So, how can I run it via mvn? I just tried `mvn test` now, it failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241962/discussion-between-max-daroshchanka-and-the-man).

Comment: 1) Adding @Optional value: `public void defineBrowser(@Optional("CHROME") String browser)` will allow to run `RunCucumberNGTest` directly, but with hardcoded default argument.

Comment: 2) `how can I run it via mvn` - I think you have to define `maven-surefire-plugin` in your `pom.xml`. And in plugin configuration set `suiteXmlFiles` value. Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391312/testng-surefire-run-suite-with-maven-command-line . If you'll hardcode the xml, the command will be `mvn clean test`. Or if you'll define some suiteName argument: `mvn clean test -DsuiteName=".../testng.xml"`

Comment: Adding `@Optional value: public void defineBrowser(@Optional("CHROME") String browser)` allows the test to run via `RunCucumberNGTest ` directly, but only on Chrome. If I change it to `FF`, it runs only on Firefox. The 2 browsers are only running together if I run via `testng.xml`

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to run one class for both browsers without testng.xml